# Why doesn't MinGW show up in the list of Eclipse/Indigo CDT Toolchains?

Tags: mingw, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to set up a C/C++ development environment on Eclipse (Indigo) running on my Windows 7 desktop. I have installed MinGW onto my C drive [per the instructions at eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-124.htm), and added the environment variable *MINGW_HOME* set to *C:\MinGW* and added *C:\MinGW\bin* to my path.

When I run eclipse and try to create a new C or C++ project, I should be seeing MinGW as one of the available Toolchains in the project creation wizard dialog. Instead, all I see in the list of available toolchains is:

> --Other Toolchain--

When I select *Tool Chain Editor* from the project properties, the only selectable "Current toolchain:" is *No ToolChain*.

I can see that C:\MinGW is installed, and I can run gcc and g++ from a CMD prompt window, so I am pretty sure that I have path set correctly.

The only troubleshooting suggestion I can find at the eclipse site is [I installed MinGW toolchain on my PC but Eclipse won't find it](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_installed_MinGW_toolchain_on_my_PC_but_Eclipse_won.27t_find_it.) but none of those suggestions work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I had the same problem: adding the System Variable `MINGW_HOME=C:\MinGW-4.7.1` and appending `C:\MinGW-4.7.1\bin` to the System Variable `Path` fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you need to install the toolchain separately. One toolchain that I found:

[llvm4eclipsecdt](http://code.google.com/p/llvm4eclipsecdt/) is available at the [eclipse marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/toolchain).

There may be other toolchains for MinGW development as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse open Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> new C/C++ Project Wizard
Make sure the Checkbox ("Show project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platform") at the bottom of the window is not ticked.